Duplicating a node is causing the resources to be linked with each other
Shifted to Godot from Unity and while I'm enjoying everything this one thing is bugging me a lot. I have read that duplicating a node in Godot does not make it's resources unique so when you change one, it'll change the other as well. Problem is, my node are not un-linking despite making the resource unique.
Here's what's happening:

Made a 3D node
Attached a MeshRenderer3D with it (cube)
Duplicated it
Attached a Material with one node - it got attached with other already (I wanted to change color of one)
Found out I have to click on arrow besides material and select "Make Unique"
Made it unique - still changing color would change the color of other node as well
Removed the materail from both. Made the resource unique. Added material back - again connected.

Can someone guide a beginner please? My use case is I have to make a lot of cuboids with different colors so not being able to use CMD + D to duplicated without making them unique is quite frustrating (heck I can't even unlike them manually anyway).

Just create a node type "MeshInstance3D" and do this in property addresses that I mention them:

From "Inspector>Mesh" drop down set it to "New BoxMesh".
From "Inspector>GeometeryInstance3D>Material Override" set it to "NewStandardMaterial3D" and click on it and set its "Albedo>Color" to your desired color.
Make that material to unique as you know.
see the sample image I attached!
Two cubes with unique albedo color


Yeah but that way I'll have to readjust the size of "New BoxMesh" again. I want to dublicate the current node with pre-set size (x, y, z) and just change the color. But when I do so, it changes the color of another as well.

Ah nvm - I can skip the first step and still just override the material. That works man. Thanks!
